# How many tasks should be created for parallelizing independent distinct DB Calls?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, task-parallel-library, task

I have 5 parallel DB operations need to be executed independently. I know asking number of Cores and creating 4 or 8 ( In case 4 or 8 cores ) tasks would be costly.

DB Op result1 = db.Table1.Get(...).Join( anotherTable2)...Join()..

DB Op result2 = db.Table1.Get(...).Join( anotherTable2)...Join()..

DB Op result3 = db.Table1.Get(...).Join( anotherTable2)...Join()..

DB Op result4 = db.Table1.Get(...).Join( anotherTable2)...Join()..

DB Op result5 = db.Table1.Get(...).Join( anotherTable2)...Join()..

On the result of these operations , I have to decide, whether I should continue further or not.

For this, couple of tasks would be sufficient which would send calls to DB for execute these operations or 5 distinct tasks should be created? I don't internally tasks create how many threads to perform certain DB operation.

I am not thinking about parallelizing query itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many tasks should be created for parallelizing independent distinct DB
>   Calls?

As many as you have independent distinct DB operations.

Wrong question.

The real question is - how many should be executed at the same time. Which means making your own limiting scheduler (copy/paste from internet). You can start at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.100).aspx - "How to: Create a Task Scheduler That Limits the Degree of Concurrency"

And that is likely trial and error because it depends on the load and characteristics of the database server, NOT the computer your code runs on. Last time I did that it was with simple operations (not a lot of join) and against an Oracle ExaData and we literally used hundreds of threads in the applicaton in parallel (way more than cores because they were mostly WAITING FOR THE DATABASE SERVER). There is no way for the C# side to know when the db server overloads, so we got them as configuration value and made some trial/error runs to find good values for the scheduler.

Comment: That's right , that C# code have no idea when DB would return the result. But I can see my distinct DB operations which have no dependence on each other. That's why I need them to execute in parallel. 

I would create a parent task which would continue if these internal 5 DB tasks would return some successful values

Comment: Oh, the C# side has a lot of knowledge about then whte DB returns. It just does not know how BUSY THE DB SERVER IS. It can well be that 2 parallel operations already overload the db server and the 3rd one makes it a lot slower. But you can not see that from within the C# application.

Comment: So, What should be done? Does distinct db calls to SQL server ( at max 4 tables would be involved per Task ) should not be parallelize in TPL way?

I want parallel execution but don't know how tasks should be created for executing 5 operations in parallel

Comment: You should read my answer and let someone do the job who can understand it? Implement a custom limiting scheduler, and then find out by analysis how many parallel operations are acceptable on the server. Do you want me to repeat it a third time?

Comment: OK, I am looking into this CustomSchedular.
Probably my point was If you create long running tasks ( you know that they would tak 3-5 minutes ) and therefore, you can create those tasks As "LongRunningOperations", so in this way , a complete thread is dedicated.

But I am sure, these all DB oeprations are just normal joins on couple of tables and those tables also have few hundred rows. In that case , I have no idea, how many threads would spawn under each task.

Comment: There is no need for long running tasks if you know C# in a modern way. ASYNC calls are your friend. Internally this creates subtasks so the thread never waits.